# Не добавляется класс после удаления jquery

Tags: jquery

Хочу реализовать удаление и появления фотографий с использованием классов.

Делаю так

```
$('#cart img').addClass('animated zoomOut');
                setTimeout(function(){$('#cart img').removeClass('animated zoomOut')}, 1000);
                setTimeout(function(){$('#cart img').addClass('animated zoomIn')}, 500);


                setTimeout(function(){$('#cart img').removeClass('animated zoomIn')}, 1000);
```

Почему то класс zoomin не добавляется. Почему?

Comment: можешь сделать [mcve]? пока вроде должно все работать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А так?

```
$('#cart img').addClass('animated zoomOut');
setTimeout(function(){$('#cart img').removeClass('animated zoomOut')}, 1000);
setTimeout(function(){$('#cart img').addClass('animated zoomIn')}, 1000 + 500);
setTimeout(function(){$('#cart img').removeClass('animated zoomIn')}, 1000 + 500 + 1000);
```

Более грамотный, но сложный для понимания вариант:

```
$('#cart img').addClass('animated zoomOut');
setTimeout(
    function() {
        $('#cart img').removeClass('animated zoomOut');
        setTimeout(
            function() {
                $('#cart img').addClass('animated zoomIn');
                setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#cart img').removeClass('animated zoomIn');
                    },
                    1000);
            }, 500);
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

setTimeout не останавливает выполнение скрипта, а указывает, что функцию нужно будет запустить через n милисекунд (или что там).
Поэтому, фактически, у Вас выполняется всё в таком порядке:

```
1. addClass('animated zoomOut') (сразу)
2. addClass('animated zoomIn') (через полсекунды)
3. removeClass('animated zoomOut') (еще через полсекунды)
4. removeClass('animated zoomIn') (сразу после предыдущего)
```

На счет последних двух не уверен, что раньше выполнится (3 или 4) - я не помню как там в javascript "складывается" выполнение setTimeout-ов - очередь там или стек. Обычно я просто не полагаюсь ни на такие явления.

Comment: Вопрос в то что после удаления класса  setTimeout(function(){$('#cart img').removeClass('animated zoomOut')}, 1000); он не устанавливает класс setTimeout(function(){$('#cart img').addClass('animated zoomIn')}, 500);

Comment: Я же и пишу, в каком порядке у Вас в самом деле происходит. В принципе некорректно в этом случае говорить, что он "не устанавливает zoomIn после remove zoomOut", потому что установка zoomIn происходит **до** того как Вы делаете "remove zoomOut".

Comment: @duddeniska, вот представьте, Вы в макдаке стоите, Вас 4 человека одновременно заказали бургер, каждому из Вас сказали, что он будет через 5 минут. Когда он будет у вас всех? Правильно, через 5 минут у каждого, у всех одновременно (с небольшой погрешностью). Также и с setTimeout.